# Is CORS support safe for cloud implementation?

Tags: ajax, wcf, web-services, security, cross-domain

There are some issues that microsoft teams have solved them for developers like following:

1. [Implementing CORS support in WCF](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Implementing-CORS-support-c1f9cd4b)
2. [Implementing CORS support in ASP.NET Web APIs](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2012/02/20/implementing-cors-support-in-asp-net-web-apis.aspx)

After reading them I was a bit confused.
I want to know something but it is conceptual matter not implementation issue. I'm going to use cors support because I'm going to build cloud distributed application which is enable to calculated data and transfer them to client and store the result, there are many clients who are connected and use information in order to their permission.

There are four tiers on three different server-computers :

1. Database Tier
2. Entities and Data Repositories
3. WCF Services Application
4. Web Application Client

Tier 4 web application use ajax functionality and may be jquery as client framework and it could be written using MVC or MVVM design pattern.

I have two choices first design extra controller layer or local web application services in tier number four and then exchange information to wcf service application in tier 3, but the second choice is applying CORS support to directly join my client framework to wcf services.

I think two of choices are possible but I don't know the side effects on each of them the clear issue for using controller is writing more codes and more heavy architecture, but what else how about for security which one is better to implement?

Please let me know about what are possible ways to connect between client and SOAP Services and which way is more logical or what is it's implementation cost.

Comment: It all depends on your authentication - is this implemented at tier 3 or does tier 4 check this before returning content? Is T3 already internet facing?

Comment: Tier 3 is private but tier four use it but about authentication I don't know exactly because I'm afraid of personal information or some data if I want to use my service using jquery directly (CORS support)  it is more risky but in the other side web application are going to heavier. which one is better ? I can put the authentication on the each of them but I think authentication for wcf service application can be more secure if I want to access directly using CORS support

Comment: The security considerations purely from a CORS point of view is similar if the user has an authentication cookie to the tier (whether this is to T3 or T4), in that another domain can make a request to resources on your domain and retrieve the response. Simply make sure the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is set appropriately. From an architecture point of view, making the service requests to T4 from the web adds an extra layer of security but if T3 is configured correctly then you need to assess whether this extra layer adds value considering the extra development time.

Comment: what do you suggest about correct configuration for T3, could explain more or post an answer?

Comment: If you could update your question with a typical WCF method example in your service and details of how authentication is achieved, then maybe I could help? Thanks.